# Problema na inserção de elementos em uma fila

Tags: c, fila

Fiz uma função utilizando o conceito de fila estática para inserir um elemento, porém, não está executando quando chamo ela no main.
Não sei se o problema está nela, na função main ou nas duas rs... segue função de inserção:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define tamanho_fila 5

int menu(){
   int opc;
   printf("[1]QUEUE\t");
   printf("[2]DEQUEUE\t");
   printf("[3]FREE QUEUE\t");
   printf("[4]SHOW FIRST ELEMENT\t");
   printf("[5]SHOW ALL ELEMENTS\t\n");
   printf("\nPLEASE, CHOOSE ANY OPTION:  ");
   scanf("%i", &opc);
   return opc;
}

struct queue{
   int inicio;
   int qtd;
   int elemento[tamanho_fila];
};

int fila_vazia(struct queue *q){
   if(q->qtd==0)
          return 1;
   return 0;
}

void inserir_fim_fila(struct queue *q, int vlr){
   int fim;
   if(q->qtd==tamanho_fila){
          printf("CAPACIDADE MAXIMA DA FILA ESTOUROU\n");
          exit(0);
   }else{
          fim=(q->inicio+q->qtd)%tamanho_fila;
          q->elemento[fim]=vlr;
          q->qtd++;
   }
}

int remover_inicio_fila(struct queue *q){
   int aux;
   if(fila_vazia(q)){
          printf("IMPOSSIVEL REMOVER, FILA VAZIA");
          return 0;
   }else{
          aux=q->elemento[q->inicio];
          q->inicio=(q->inicio+1)%tamanho_fila;
          q->qtd--;
          return 1;
   }
}

void mostrar_fila(struct queue *q){
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<q->qtd;i++){
          printf("%i", q->elemento);
   }
}

void free_queue(struct queue* q){
   free(q);
}

int main(){
   int opc, vlr;
   struct queue *q;
  while(opc==menu()){
          switch(opc){
                 case 1:
                        printf("INSERT ELEMENT: ");
                        scanf("%i", &vlr);
                        inserir_fim_fila(&q, vlr);
                        break;
                 case 3:
                        free_queue(&q);
                        break;
          };
   system("pause");
   }
    return 0;
}
```

Espero que possam ajudar!

Comment: Olá Camilla! Você pode postar seu código completo, ou algo próximo do explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), por favor? =]

Comment: @Blogueira, sim claro.. editei minha pergunta..

Comment: Camilla - alguém vai ter que responder melhor isso aqui (alguém que entenda!), mas para você continuar trabalhando, acho que tem um igual a mais: `while(opc==menu()){}`. Provavelmente deveria ser `while(opc=menu()){}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom reescrevi seu código com algumas alterações por que do jeito que estava ele a lógica estava um pouco confusa. Desculpe a minha resposta editada.

O seu código a princípio no main estava apenas com a struct declarada com ponteiro, mas na verdade com fila estática você trabalha através de referência.

Eu criei uma função para inicializar a Fila, o que é essencial, pois você precisa de sua fila inicie com valores.

Na função de inserção você sempre vai adicionar sempre o elemento no final da fila já que o objetivo de Fila é o "primeiro a entrar o primeiro a sair" então a variável **qtd** vai marcar o final da Fila então toda vez que você adicionar um elemento você vai incrementar ela.

Na remoção você sempre vai remover do início da fila então você terá a variável **inicio** marcando qual o primeiro elemento para sair da fila.

Continue a sua implementação a partir desse código que eu acho que vai dar certo. Desculpe entrei na comunidade agora e não tenho muita prática de ensinar através de postagens.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define tamanho_fila 5

struct queue{
   int inicio;
   int qtd;
   int elemento[tamanho_fila];
};

int menu(){
   int opc;
   printf("[1]QUEUE\t");
   printf("[2]DEQUEUE\t");
   printf("[3]FREE QUEUE\t");
   printf("[4]SHOW FIRST ELEMENT\t");
   printf("[5]SHOW ALL ELEMENTS\t\n");
   printf("\nPLEASE, CHOOSE ANY OPTION:  ");
   scanf("%i", &opc);
   return opc;
}

void inicFila(struct queue *q){
    q->qtd=-1;
    q->inicio = 0;
}

int fila_vazia(struct queue *q){
   if(q->qtd<q->inicio)
          return 1;
   return 0;
}

int inserir_fim_fila(struct queue *q, int vlr){
   int fim;
   if(q->qtd == tamanho_fila-1){
          printf("CAPACIDADE MAXIMA DA FILA ESTOUROU\n");
          return 1;
   }else
        return q->elemento[++(q->qtd)] = vlr;
}

int remover_inicio_fila(struct queue *q){
   int aux;
   if(fila_vazia(q)){
          printf("IMPOSSIVEL REMOVER, FILA VAZIA");
          return 0;
   }else{
          aux=q->elemento[q->inicio];
          q->inicio++;
          return aux;
   }
}

void mostrar_fila(struct queue *q){
   int i;
   if(!fila_vazia(&q)){
       for(i=0;i<q->qtd;i++){
              printf("%i", q->elemento[i]);
       }
   }
   else printf("A fila não tem nenhum elemento.");
}

void free_queue(struct queue* q){
   free(q);
}

int main(){
    int opc, vlr;
    struct queue q;
    inicFila(&q);
    while(opc=menu()){
            switch(opc){
                    case 1:
                        printf("INSERT ELEMENT: ");
                        scanf("%i", &vlr);
                        inserir_fim_fila(&q, vlr);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        free_queue(&q);
                        break;
            };
    system("pause");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Olá Luiz, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow! Normalmente as respostas dadas aqui "solucionam" o problema - para tirar dúvidas, usa-se o campo de comentários (que você poderá usar em breve, quando tiver mais reputação). Por enquanto, sugiro que você responda apenas perguntas claras que dê para dar uma solução certeira.

Comment: Olá! O %tamanho_fila é para indicar onde o fim da fila está localizado no vetor, para isso eu preciso somar a quantidade de itens + índice do início % tamanho_fila.. exemplo: 2+4/5 = significa que o fim da fila está no índice 1.. Enfim, eu executo o sistema e ele chega a rodar, mas nem pergunta espera eu inserir o elemento e ele já fecha... talvez o problema esteja na main

Comment: Olá pessoal, Obrigado pelas boas vindas @Blogueira entendo suas dicas, acabei de entrar na comunidade espero que eu possa ajudar outras pessoas com os códigos. Editei minha resposta você pode conferir agora. Obrigado pela compreensão. Até mais.

Comment: Boa! Você pode utilizar sites com o [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/c) para demonstrar o código em funcionamento (além, é claro, de colocá-lo no texto) - costuma agregar valor à resposta! ;)

Comment: @LuizEduardoC. muito obrigada pela ajuda!!